# Coordinates of a segment formed by the sum of two angles

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

If I add two arbitrary angles *A* + *D*, how do I find the coordinates of the arc formed by *GH*?

Corners *C* and *B* can be swapped.
Corners *E* and *F* can be swapped.
As long as *A* and *D* get added together.

Let
*r = 1*
*A = 22.5 degrees*
*D = 45 degrees*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, say your angles are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In polar coordinates your red dots will be 
$$(r,\theta) = (1,0),(1,\alpha+\beta).$$
Convert to Cartesian:
$$ (x,y) = (1,0),(\cos(\alpha+\beta),\sin(\alpha+\beta)). $$
If you want the equation of the arc itself, just parametrize the curve. In particular, the parametrization is
$$ (x,y) = (\cos t,\sin t)$$
Where $t$ varies in $[0,\alpha+\beta]$.